# Workflow doesn't start because no record is inserted in Workflow Tasks list

Tags: task, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

In my site I have created a group called `My Members` and I assigned `Contribute` permission to it. I deleted all others SharePoint default groups. I have included `Everyone` in this group.

`Workflow Tasks` list is inheriting from top level site so it also includes this `My Members` group.

I have created a custom SharePoint 2013 workflow in SPD. It is supposed to run when user creates new item in a custom list but problem is when a user creates new item in this list, no record is being inserted in `Workflow Tasks` list so workflow doesn't run.

Even if I assign `Design` or `Approve` or `Full Control` permission, it doesn't work i.e. when user creates a new item in list, workflow is not started because no record is inserted in `Workflow Tasks` list. Although in that custom list, item is successfully created.

Unless I give this `My Members` group `Site Collection Administrator` permission, user is unable to create new entry in `Workflow Tasks`

By the way once item has been created in the custom list, I am assigning unique permission on that item by removing all permission and just giving `Read` permission to the user who created this item, and `Contribute` permission to user to whom task is assigned. May be this is what is causing the issue!?

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open SPD, click workflows from left menu and click your workflow. There is a settings area. Check your task list. Make sure that it is "Workflow Tasks" or not.

Also do not add item with farm admin. Try with normal user.